# IIS can access from Default Web Site bur cannot access newly created web site

Tags: iis

After the IIS is setup. I can browse the default web site remotely i.e [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) but I'm not able to access the new site that I have just created v_sp.mydomain.com 
I attached my setup photo[image]

The domain is hosted by godaddy.

Comment: What do you get from `nslookup v_sp.mydomain.com` at command prompt? Is that IP address correct which can pass the traffic to this IIS machine?

Comment: I have resolved by adding additional setting on  godaddy. Thanks @LexLi

Comment: You might post the solution you found as an answer and accept it.